# ACE TAO cannot get NameService object in debug mode

Tags: ace, tao, nameservice

I'm running a multi-program projects using ACE TAO. I set the Environment Variables and compiled ACE_TAO environment. Then I copied the `tao_cosnaming.exe` to my project run directory and use a .bat to start the naming service.

The programs run well if I start them directly, but they could not get the "NameService" correctly when I invoke obj = orb->resolve_initial_references("NameService") in debug mode.  (I could not run  obj->_non_existent(), it throws an error).

It seemed because the Naming Service is implemented as a remote one. When I invoke obj = orb->invoke resolve_initial_references("RootPOA"), things are fine, because RootPOA is local object so obj->_non_existent() return immediately.

The .bat file is like:

```
cd /D %DTAX_RUN_DIR%
tao_cosnaming -ORBEndPoint iiop://%DTAX_NAME_SERVICE_HOST%
```

The `DTAX_RUN_DIR` and `DTAX_NAME_SERVICE_HOST` are Environment Variables. `DTAX_RUN_DIR` is project run directory and `DTAX_NAME_SERVICE_HOST=169.254.51.81:10493`

Could anybody share some ideas on what is going wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Anybody??? Please!!! Help!!!!

Comment: do you pass to your program the IIOP endpoint of the Naming Service also? A much better place to ask this is the tao-users mailing list, see http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE-mail.html

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give a definite solution with just the information you provided, but in my projects I need to pass "-c" (without the quotes) as a command argument so that I can debug it, maybe you need to do the same.
In Visual Studio in the project properties you can find the Command arguments field in Properties/Debugging.